# Sum-to-zero constraints in a two-way ANOVA model

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I'm reviewing my lecture notes on sum-to-zero constraints and I am having a tough time understanding the concept.

Say the constraints are $\sum_{i=1}^{a} \alpha_i = 0$, $\sum_{j=1}^{b} \beta_j = 0$, $\sum_{i=1}^{a} (\alpha \beta)_{ij} = 0$ for $j = 1,...,b$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{b} (\alpha \beta)_{ij} = 0$ for $i = 1,...,a$.

Here are the following questions I have:

1) Why does this represent $a + b + 1$ independent constraints and not $a + b + 2$ independent constraints?

2) How do I determine that there are $a-1$ linearly independent $\alpha_i$'s, $b-1$ linearly independent $\beta_j$'s and $(a-1)(b-1)$ linearly independent $(\alpha \beta ) _{ij}$'s?

Thanks in advance.